# Rank deficient LDPC code

Tags: galois-theory, coding-theory

I am new to working on LDPC codes and have gotten stuck on this issue for some time. I am struggling on how to deal with parity check matrices that are not of full rank. I generate the parity check matrix using Gallager's construction (see example 1.14 http://sigpromu.org/sarah/SJohnsonLDPCintro.pdf) and then attempt to get the result into systematic form, so that the matrix describes the information part and the parity part. When I do this however I am left with one or more all zero rows and to double check I checked the rank and it is indeed not full rank matrix.

The question I have is, what do I do when the parity check matrix starts out as not full rank? How do I get the systematic form and then the generator matrix? And what is the meaning of the parity check matrix not being full rank?

Comment: If you construct this matrix in a random way, we can get a parity check matrix which is not full rank effectively. The redundant columns are useless for a code construction point of view. You can suppress them to get a systematic construction. But pay attention that this encoding method is not suitable for large sizes, as the obtained generating matrix is not sparse. For a decoding point a view, you can keep these redundant columns: the iterative decoding process is not optimal and you may loose in performance by suppressing these columns

Comment: @Damien That makes sense, thank you. The redundant columns are in some way representing a coded bit that it doesn't matter what its value is? Is this a correct way of thinking of the redundant columns?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you are supposed to do the decoding with the original sparse check matrix. Linear dependencies among the check equations do create cycles in the Tanner graph, but unless they are relatively short, they won't disturb the decoding much. To have efficient encoding you do need to know the set of information positions at least. A high weight generator matrix may be bad for filling in the check positions. I'm afraid I'm not up to speed with all the related aspects for I have only ever seriously looked at LDPC codes with a little bit of extra structure.